# Xamarin forms CollectionView with incremental loading initialization

Tags: xamarin.forms

When using CollectionView with incremental loading how to know I have to stop my initial load?

Documentation provides nothing about how to initialize ItemsSource when you want to load data incrementally. Every example I found use a random number of items at initial load and hope it will be enough to have a scroll and then trigger `RemainingItemsThresholdReached` when needed.

But it depends on the device size and current orientation, if my initial load is too short for the current screen then user won't be able to scroll and no data will be loaded. On the other side if my initial load is too long we are loosing the interest of incremental load.

Is it the expected behaviour? Am I missing something?

I guess I could detect when to stop my first load according to the current device screen size and my item size but it sounds weird.

Comment: is it really that difficult to make an educated guess about how many UI elements will fit on your page for a given device idiom?

Comment: No it is not and it works but it's not my question. I'm not looking for a workaround I know how to workaround it. I want to know if there is a proper way to do that. A way which not involves computing in each views how many ui items (for the current view) will fit.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think there is any "proper" way.  People just make an educated guess based on their UI design.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What would you think about raising "RemainingItemsThresholdReached" when appearing or when item is added if threshold is reached even without scroll? It was my first try but is not fired without scroll

Comment: RemainingItemsThresholdReached will only fire after scrolling.